# Get Current User Desktop Path using PHP - WampServer

Tags: php, desktop, wampserver

By using the code:

```
echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH");
```

I'm getting the path to Desktop (C:\Users\my_user\Desktop) in Xampp. But the same code is not working poperly in WampServer. It's returning null value. I don't know how to correct this issue.

Please Help me..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your Wampserver on a different machine? Because environment variables are stored in your windows profile, every programe ran in your user context can see them. Ah, that might be it,... **Which user** is running Xampp, and which user is running WampServer? (Use `echo getenv("USER");` with both webserver stacks.)

Comment: WampServer & Xampp are installed in the same machine and is run by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

The function getenv() you gives you the value of environment variables set with your web server either your local computer acting as web server or even remote server.

Different development servers store the values of environment variables differently, due to this WAMP is acting differently and XAMPP is differently on your computer.

Try to make call to phpinfo() function, and you will see the complete list of all environment variables available in current installation. For more detailed information see the link below

https://www.php.net/getenv

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Happy Coding!

Thanks

Atul Jindal

Comment: I have also tried `getenv("USERPROFILE")`. In Xampp it's returning the path **C:\Users\my_user**, but in Wamp it's returning **C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile**.

Comment: I have tried the **phpinfo()** function & can see the differences. But please tell me how to Get Current User Desktop Path in WAMP

Comment: Can you 100% confirm Wampserver and Xampp run the same user? It sounds more like Xampp is running with your local user and Wampserver is running with a system user.... or at least, Wampserver is running as a windows system service and Xampp is running standalone.

Comment: How can I confirm Wampserver and Xampp are run the same user or not?

Comment: Well it depends upon during the installation and your system's Environment variables.