# how to get environment variables desktop path

Tags: php, codeigniter, environment-variables

can someone help me to get DESKTOP PATH?

```
echo "<input type='hidden' value='C:\Users\".getenv('USERNAME')."\Desktop'>";
```

it returns **C:\Users\IT-TUPER$\Desktop**

this is my desktop path **C:\Users\Tuper\Desktop**

Comment: Have you tried FCPATH

Comment: i want to get the computer DESKTOP PATH... and i searched about FCPATH it seems it will not give me the DESKTOP PATH...

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037392/get-current-user-desktop-path-using-php-wampserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php by no means you can't have Desktop Path on a real server, as php is serverside. However if you're on localhost like xampp, wamp, or whatever on windows you try this :

```
<?php  echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH")."\Desktop";  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are in server, the client (browser) ask a petition to server (specific php file), the server render the answer, send it to client (browser).

For that reason, you can´t get client path.